# SELECT range from Map in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have table in Cassandra and I wish to select 10 last `blob` from `usermgmt.user_history.history`

```
CREATE TABLE usermgmt.user_history (
  id        uuid, 
  history   Map<timeuuid, blob>,
  PRIMARY   KEY(id)
);
```

I feel like it was easy with 5 year old Cassandra design with ordered typed column names. But now I can't find method to select range of 10 last entries in recent Cassandra 3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
CREATE TABLE usermgmt.user_history (
  id        uuid, 
  history_time timestamp,
  history_blob blob,
  PRIMARY   KEY(id, history_time)
);
```

Then,

```
SELECT * FROM usermgmt.user_history WHERE id = your-uuid ORDER BY history_time limit 10;
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Do you have any idea if 5 years old solution is possible?

Comment: Sorry, I used Cassandra after the changes :)